# Add multiple new produtcs to Org pricebooks

Tags: apex, trigger, pricebook

I'm coding a tringger which takes all the new products and inserts them automatically in the Org's pricebooks. Now:
-newProd is a list of new Products
-notStandardPB is the list of Org's pricebooks
Below you find my code:

```
PricebookEntry notStandardPBE = new PricebookEntry();
        for(Pricebook2 p:notStandardPB){
            for(Product2 prodTopbb : newProd){
                System.debug(prodTopbb.Id);
                notStandardPBE.Pricebook2Id = p.Id;
                notStandardPBE.Product2Id = prodTopbb.Id;
                notStandardPBE.UseStandardPrice = true;
                notStandardPBE.IsActive=true;            
                pbeNotStandardList.add(notStandardPBE);
            }  
        }
        System.debug('non standard pb: '+pbeNotStandardList);
        System.debug('non standard pb: '+pbeNotStandardList.size());
        insert pbeNotStandardList;
```

When trigger fires the System throws the error: "System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements". Infact seems like the trigger takes only the first product's Id and I don't understand why. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not re-initialising the elements you are adding to the collection.

move this line inside the for loop and it should resolve the error

```
PricebookEntry notStandardPBE = new PricebookEntry();
```

Comment: Shame on me :P. Thank you, I don't know why but I don't see it